# No suitable ServiceConnectorCreator

Tags: cloud, datasource, cloud-foundry, pcf, pivotal-web-services

I am trying to push a spring application to PCF. In doing so, I get the following error: The user provided services exist.

> Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceNWTC' defined in class path resource [com/***/**/****/***/**/config/CloudConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource com.*****.**.**.**.**.config.CloudConfig.nwPrepDataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No suitable ServiceConnectorCreator found: service id=dataSource-NWTC, service info type=org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo, connector type=interface javax.sql.DataSource

I have tried this with several versions.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
```

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>repository.springsource.milestone</id>
    <name>SpringSource Milestone Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
  </repository>
```

```
@Configuration
@ServiceScan
@Profile("cloud")
public class CloudConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

  @Bean(name = "dataSourceAIMS")
  public DataSource aimsDataSource() {
    return connectionFactory().dataSource("dataSource-AIMS");
  }

  @Bean(name = "dataSourceNWTC")
  public DataSource nwPrepDataSource() {
    return connectionFactory().dataSource("dataSource-NWTC");
  }
}
```

---

```
applications:
- name: some-name
  path: target/some-name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
  random-route: true
  buildpacks: 
  - java_buildpack_offline
  services:
  - dataSource-AIMS
  - dataSource-NWTC
 env:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No suitable ServiceConnectorCreator found

You'll see this when Spring Cloud Connectors doesn't know how to make a service object from the service info it's got in `VCAP_SERVICES`. Look at `VCAP_SERVICES` and see if the type of service is [supported by SCC](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_relational_database_db2_mysql_oracle_postgresql_sql_server). Also, look and confirm that the service info is structured in a way that the supported DB types would be able to understand.

---

Aside from that, I would strongly suggest you take a look at [java-cfenv](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv) instead of Spring Cloud Connectors. I believe that is intended to be the successor to Spring Cloud Connectors.

https://spring.io/blog/2019/02/15/introducing-java-cfenv-a-new-library-for-accessing-cloud-foundry-services

Hope that helps!

Comment: cf cups dataSource -p {"uri"} \n
{uri}>  oracle://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<serviceName>               This  fixed the issue. I think I created the service wrong. Looks like you have to provide the uri in a specific format for the connector to determine what type to use.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. SCC is looking for the `oracle://` even though that's not what a typical Oracle JDBC URL would look like.